# How to calculate mean values per group and sort the output by that mean in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like this:

```
color    power
red      6
red      8
green    3
red      1
yellow   10
green    5
```

What I want is this:

```
color   mean_of_power
yellow  10
red     5
green   4
```

I have tried `df.groupby("color")["power"].mean()`, but this will give me a dataframe sorted alphabetically:

```
color   mean_of_power
green   4
red     5
yellow  10
```

How can I group a dataframe by one column (`color`), calculate the mean of another column (`power`) per group and sort the output by the value of that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `sort_values` right after that:

```
df.groupby("color").power.mean().sort_values(ascending=False)
```

---

Or to create an additional column with count which we sort by:

```
(df.groupby("color").power
   .agg(["mean", "count"])
   .rename(columns="{}_of_power".format)
   .sort_values("count_of_power", ascending=False))

# output: 
        mean_of_power  count_of_power
color                                
red               5.0               3
green             4.0               2
yellow           10.0               1
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. Do you know how I would sort by something else? Like by the count of colors, so that I get them in the order `red`, `green`, `yellow`?

Comment: @C4X See update answer. Should be fairly self-explanatory. Remove steps from the back to see what each one does.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby("color")["power"].mean().sort_values('mean_of_power')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This doesn't work since I don't have a column called `mean_of_power`.